# Unable to get a result less than 1 using division c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, recursion

I'm attempting to use a recursive function to halve a user input until it reaches <1.0..  No matter what I try it always ends with a result > 1.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
void counter(float count) 
{
    if (count >= 1)
    {
        cout  << count << endl;
        counter(count / 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, if it's less than 1.0, you never print it. Maybe you want the `cout` statement before the `if`.

Comment: is there no way to achieve what I am attempting?

Comment: add a cout after the if statement.  That will be the last function call.

Comment: that fixed it... thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print `count` when it becomes less than `1`, you need to add a line for that.

```
void counter(float count) 
{
    if (count >= 1)
    {
        cout  << count << endl;
        counter(count / 2);
    }
    else
    {
       cout  << count << endl;
    }
}
```

You can simplify that by using:

```
void counter(float count) 
{
    cout  << count << endl;
    if (count >= 1)
    {
        counter(count / 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are almost there...

add an else to check what is going to happen if the value is less than 1.0

```
void counter(float count) 
{
    if (count >= 1)
    {
        cout  << count << endl;
        counter(count / 2);
    } else
    {
        cout  << count << endl;
    }  
}
```